# How to insert an image in an HTML document in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: html, linux, image, redhat

I tried to insert an image in HTML document in Red hat Linux, but it doesn't display the image. The rest content is being displayed.

Comment: The code? inserting an image is done with the <img> tag.

Comment: Do you mean you need an image tag? <img src='http://google.com/favicon.ico '>   This would have nothing to do with your OS.

Comment: Give us the code.. so that we can help...

Comment: Can you please provide more information on like what you trying to do and where you trying to insert??

Comment: This can be closed as Unclear or Lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have given the correct path. HTML doesn't vary with OS.

Comment: Guys thank you for showing interest. the problem got solved. actually i created a local host in Linux Red hat. and there I tried to save this html document. when I saved the same document on Desktop the image came itself...
Thank You All... ♥ :-D

Answer (score 0):

Check you're using consistent (upper or lower) case for both the image file name AND extension in your HTML, ie, consistent with the name of what's stored on the server ...